# Netlogo: Ask specific turtle to do something

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to simulate a car factory using robots called `carriers`. In my go method i'm trying to ask one carriers who is not on a job to find a `cutter` and go to it.

How do I ask the specific carrier to do something?

This is what i've done so far:

````
metal-sheets
cut-sheets
standard-skeleton
finished-standard-skeleton
prestige-skeleton
finished-prestige-skeleton
]

breed[carriers carrier]

turtles-own [
on-job?
]

patches-own [
processing-time
  machine-type ;;cutter, standard-welder, prestige-welder, riveter
  status ;;import, export, pending
]

to setup
  set-default-shape carriers "circle"
  create-carriers number-of-carriers
  [set color grey
  set on-job? false]
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    if pxcor = 1 and pycor = 1 [set machine-type "cutter"]
    if pxcor = 1 and pycor = 5 [set machine-type "standard-welder"]
    if pxcor = 5 and pycor = 1 [set machine-type "prestige-welder"]
    if pxcor = 5 and pycor = 5 [set machine-type "riveter"]

    if machine-type = "cutter" 
    [set pcolor red
    set status "import"]
    if machine-type = "standard-welder" 
    [set pcolor green
    set status "import"]
    if machine-type = "prestige-welder" 
    [set pcolor blue
    set status "import"]
    if machine-type = "riveter" 
    [set pcolor yellow
    set status "import"]
  ]
end

to Go

  let cutter patches with [machine-type = "cutter"]
    let standard-welder patches with [machine-type = "standard-welder"]
    let prestige-welder patches with [machine-type = "prestige-welder"]
    let riveter patches with [machine-type = "riveter"]

  let free-carriers carriers with [in-job? false]

  ask free-carriers [
     ;;on-job is a carrier-owned variable
      ask cutter [
        if status = "import" [
          set status "pending"
          face cutter ;; I want the carrier to face the cutter and move towards it
          fd 1

      ]
    ]
  ]
end```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want `free-carriers` to find a cutter patch with status "import", have that cutter change its status, and then have the carrier move toward it.

```
ask free-carriers [
  ;;on-job is a carrier-owned variable
  let my-cutter one-of cutter with [status = "import"]
  if my-cutter != nobody [
    ask my-cutter [ set status "pending" ]
    face cutter ;; I want the carrier to face the cutter and move towards it
    fd 1
  ]
]
```

Since each free-carrier does this in (random) turn, no two free-carriers should go to the same cutter. This will choose an eligible cutter randomly.  You could have free-carriers go to the nearest one if you wished.